# jQuery 1.9.1 Error - Occurs with IE but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have an MVC 4 app containing a View with a form with several fieldsets. When I post this form in Chrome, it saves without error. In `IE 10.0.92` I get an error in the following jQuery method. The line throwing the error has an arrow. This is roughly line 538. I've determined this method is not even called when executing in Chrome.

```
parseJSON: function (data) {
    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) {
-->        return window.JSON.parse(data);

    }

    if (data === null) {
        return data;
    }

    if (typeof data === "string") {

        // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
        data = jQuery.trim(data);

        if (data) {
            // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
            // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
            if (rvalidchars.test(data.replace(rvalidescape, "@")
                .replace(rvalidtokens, "]")
                .replace(rvalidbraces, ""))) {

                return (new Function("return " + data))();
            }
        }
    }

    jQuery.error("Invalid JSON: " + data);
},
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

[image]

I did an alert on the value of 'data', and I get an Undefined. I don't have a great deal of experience with jQuery or JavaScript. If more information is needed, I would be glad to provide it.

After some further testing, this change seems to fix the issue, but I'm not sure this is the right approach:

```
parseJSON: function (data) {
    if (data === undefined) {
        return data;
    }

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) {
        return window.JSON.parse(data);

    }
```

Comment: What is the JSON that the code is trying to parse?

Comment: This happens in Opera too. Or maybe just us two faced it!

Comment: IE 10.0.92. And, I'm not aware that I'm sending any JSON to the server from the client. Perhaps indirectly it's being done.

Comment: In my case, I was parsing this object `'{ "Users": [{ "key": "1", "label": "Tom Clancy" }, { "key": "12", "label": "Steve Martin" }] }'`

Comment: @RandyMinder what about from the server to the client?

Comment: @DanielA.White - For this particular view, I have no JSON going from the server to the client.

Comment: Perhaps using the jQuery.parseJSON() function will solve this problem: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @rontornambe - Thanks but I'm not about to start modifying the code in the jQuery.js file. This has got to be a bug in the jQuery code.

Comment: @rontornambe OP is using `$.parseJSON` (either explicitly or implicitly through an ajax call that returns a JSON response) as you can see that his posted code is from inside the jQuery library's `parseJSON` method. @OP I guess you're better off tracking the call stack and seeing from where the error originates in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js files with Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation nuget package which version is 2.0.30506.0 
Then this error has been resolved.